# Master detail using knockout using select

Tags: javascript, wcf, knockout.js

I have the code below which will load a list:

```
<table id ="tblVersion" class="table table-striped table-hover " style="border: none" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none">Id</th>
      <th>Version Name</th>
      <th>Version Code </th>
      <th>Module Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: versionDataByProduct">
    <tr data-bind="click: $root.EditVersionDetail">
      <td data-bind="text: Id" style="display: none"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Code"></td>
      <td data-bind ="text: $root.editModuleId"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the code that loads the details when I click on a row:

```
<div  id="EditVersionDetail" style="margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 10px">
  <table data-bind ="with: selecteditem">
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Version Name</strong></td>
      <td><input id="txtVersionName" data-bind ="value:  Name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Version Code</strong></td>
      <td><input id="txtVersionCode"  data-bind="value: Code" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Module</strong></td>
      <td><select id="selModuleType"  data-bind="options: $root.modules,  optionsCaption: 'Please select Module...' , value: $root.editModuleId , optionsText: 'ModuleName'" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I click on a row the data is loaded correctly in the details part. But if I change some data in the details part, the value in the list also gets changed, except for `editModuleId`. If I select some value in the select list, this value doesn't get reflected in the list. This `editModuleId` has data coming from a different table, but has a relation with observable array "versionDataByProduct".

What should I do? Can you give me an example where values in details including dropdown are reflected in the master whenever there is change?

Comment: Could you post your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: can i mail you my code? how fiddle can be useful for this? because anyway i will paste same code i wrote above. Also i load data using WCF so dont know how could i post that in there? Can you help me on code i provided? DO you need any further explaination of my issue? I am really looking forward to any help

Comment: i added to fiddle.. see if this help you to understand my question
http://jsfiddle.net/kirannandedkar/af5n5/

Comment: I've looked at your sample.  There doesn't appear any data to fill your view model with and neither ajax function is called.

Comment: Have u looked at my fiddle? There is call to my wcf service to load data

Comment: Or have u understood my issue? I click on row and it loads detail. When i change something in detail it gets updated in master but if i select something from select list then its not reflected in master. Can u give me ex for this

Comment: look at this fiddle.. its not showing list of modules in the <li> tags. When i click on list it show detail but moduleid is not correctly set. Also if i change soemthing in select list then it should get automatically reflected in the <li> tag list.
http://jsfiddle.net/kirannandedkar/JUChh/6/

Comment: @dda: look at this fiddle.. its not showing list of modules in the <li> tags. When i click on list it show detail but moduleid is not correctly set. Also if i change soemthing in select list then it should get automatically reflected in the <li> tag list. jsfiddle.net/kirannandedkar/JUChh/6

Comment: I have got answer of my question from Arteem. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798129/knockout-master-detail-not-working-with-select